# My website is only accessible when adding port 3000

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker-compose, ip, amazon-rds, port

I can only access my website hosted on an ec2 instance when i add port 3000 in the end to my elastic Ip adress mapped to my domain name hosted on namecheap.

my docker contains ; frontend, backend, nginx and certbot.

When i build the docker project everything looks ok without any warnings.

here is a view of my docker compose yml file and .env files:

1-docker compose yml:

```
  version: '3'
     services:
   # Client container
  client:
    build:
      context: frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: client
    ports:
      - "80:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/var/www/frontend

  #Laravel App
  app:
    build:
      context: backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: hakase-labs/laravel
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "80:9000"
    environment:
      SERVICE_NAME: app
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www/backend
    volumes:
      - ./backend/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
      - ./backend:/var/www/backend
    depends_on:
      - db

  #SSL
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot:latest
    container_name: certbot
    volumes:
      - ./certbot/www/:/var/www/certbot/:rw
      - ./certbot/conf/:/etc/letsencrypt/:rw

  #Nginx Service
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      # Nuxt port
      - "80:80"
      # Laravel port
      - "81:81"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./certbot/www:/var/www/certbot/:ro
      - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt/:ro
      - ./nginx/config/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./nginx/config/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - app
      - client

  #MySQL Service
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: *******
      MYSQL_USER: **************
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: **************
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: *************
    volumes:
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql/
#Docker Networks
# networks:
  # mynet:
    # driver: bridge
#Volumes
volumes:
  mysqldata:
    driver: local
```

2-nginx default config file:

```
#--------------------------------------------------------
# Nuxt.JS server configuration
#--------------------------------------------------------
proxy_cache_path /tmp/cacheapi levels=1:2 keys_zone=microcacheapi:100m max_size=1g inactive=1d use_temp_path=off;



map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    "text/html"                 epoch;
    "text/html; charset=utf-8"  epoch;
    default                     off;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    access_log  off;
    error_log   off;
    server_name mydomain.com;


    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
         
         root /var/www/certbot;
    }


   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    access_log off;
    server_name mydomain.com;
      #ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
      #ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;


    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
         
         root /var/www/certbot;
    }
   
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        # Proxy to Node.JS instance
        proxy_pass http://client:3000;

        expires $expires;

        proxy_redirect                      off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout                  1m;
        proxy_connect_timeout               1m;

        # Websocket support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

  location ~ /\. {
    access_log    off;
    log_not_found off;
    deny all;
  }
}


server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    access_log  off;
    error_log   off;
    server_name admin.mydomain.com;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name admin.mydomain.com;
    access_log off;

    # Micro caching
    proxy_cache microcacheapi;
    proxy_cache_valid 200 1s;
    proxy_cache_use_stale updating;
    proxy_cache_background_update on;
    proxy_cache_lock on;

    #ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    #ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.mydomainy.com/privkey.pem;


location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/backend/public;
    charset utf-8;

    client_max_body_size 20m;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    # Handle all php files (which will always be just /index.php)
    # via factcgi PHP-FPM unix socket
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        # For comfortable debugging
        fastcgi_read_timeout 1000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

PS; ports 80 and 443 are allowed inside security groups of my ec2 instance.
i added 3000 port in the inbound rules as TCP and i when i add this 3000 port to my website, i can access it.

what i want is to access my website with the default http port 80.

Thanks

i tried to change the ports insid my docker compose yml file to 80 but when i build the docker image, it says that port 80 is already allocated

Comment: It is not possible to serve  two services on same port, as per your docker-compose.yml file you are trying to run client service and app service on same port.

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a docker ps once and check what is the actual port mapping being followed by your docker containers? That would be helpful to troubleshoot.